# How to Create Controller Comments in Sublime of Laravel Project?

Tags: controller, comments, sublimetext3, laravel-5.4, laravel-controller

> How to Create of the Type of Comments In Laravel Controller in Sublime Text 3 ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DocBlockr plugin for this.

https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs

Also please refer this link for more details - https://mattstauffer.com/blog/sublime-text-3-for-php-developers/

Comment: Doc Blockr Can't Plugin ...why ??

Comment: Hello ?? Not Any proccess after im hiting `DocBlocker`  for plugin... why ??

Comment: Have you installed it properly ? I am in Mac, It is working without any issues.

Comment: i'm using w10. **`Sublime>install packages>DocBlockr>Enter`** after not doing anthing. and again i will go install for package then there also this package will show. why ??

Comment: Sorry brother. I never used it in Windows.

Comment: Okay.! don't Warry